# Should I use foldr or foldl' to build a String in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, higher-order-functions, fold

Assuming that `foldr` should be used to build data structures and `foldl'` if the result is supposed to be a single value, I'm not sure what to use for Strings. On the one hand it is a data structure, but on the other hand a String is usually only used as a whole, meaning that short-circuiting isn't very relevant. To answer this question, it's probably crucial how functions like `putStrLn` use Strings, isn't it? Or am I on a completely wrong track?

EDIT: So I want my function to turn something like `[(5, 's'), (1, ’a'), (3, 'd')]` into `sssssaddd` (following an exercise from https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell) and I have to choose one from those two functions:

```hs
decode :: [(Int, Char)] -> String
decode = foldr ff []
  where
    ff (l, c) xs = replicate l c ++ xs

decode' :: [(Int, Char)] -> String
decode' = foldl' ff []
  where
    ff xs (l, c) = xs ++ replicate l c
```

Comment: `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`. Do you expect to have infinite lists of `Char`? (Consider whether you should be using `String` at all, in place of something like `Text`.)

Comment: @chepner What I wanted to say is that String, which is a data structure ([Char]) and as such should be build with foldr (because short-circuiting is "enabled"), usually doesn't need to be able to be short-circuited evaluated since you usally need the whole String and not just a part of it. I'm not quite sure where my question is unclear, maybe you can tell me what to improve on the formulation?

Comment: For lists usually `foldr`, since `foldl` will take quadratic time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the completely wrong track. The only correct way to decide what fold to use involves knowing what the fold will do. Knowing only the output type is not enough.

Comment: I added some more detail for my specific problem, but what I basically was asking for is a general rule of thumb when building Strings

Comment: @thornySoap I'm not sure how much more clearly I can say this: rules of thumb should be about the *operator you're folding*, not the *type you're producing*. Sometimes `foldr` is right for producing `String`, sometimes `foldl'` is right. Asking for a general rule of thumb when building strings is a category error.

Comment: So it's going to be be `foldr` in my concrete example, I suppose?

Comment: @thornySoap Yes, `foldr` should work well for the task you describe in the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` is just an alias of `[Char]`, so a list. If you use `foldl` or `foldl'` with append (`(++)`) or cons (`(:)`), it will fold with `foldl` as:

```
(("hell" ++ "o") ++ " ") ++ "world"
```

Concatenating takes linear time in the length of the *left* operand. So if you eacn time concatenate a single character, then constructing a string of *n* characters will take *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time.

Another problem that might arise if you have an infinite list, in that case, `foldl` will get stuck in an infinite loop. Whereas in `foldr` you can "consume" the output if that happens in a generator-like approach.

But as [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75160054/should-i-use-foldr-or-foldl-to-build-a-string-in-haskell#comment132631458_75160054) says, using `String`s for large amounts of text is not effective: it requires a *cons* per character, so it blows up in memory. [**`Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.1/docs/Data-Text.html#t:Text) allows one to have a more compact and efficient way to store text, in an unboxed type, and often the algorithms are more efficient than what one can do with a `String`.